# High-frequency performance counter sampling using perf record/report

Tags: performance, profiling, perf, perf-event

I want to retrieve performance counter counts at a high frequency (i.e. 100-200Hz) using the `perf` tool (similar in functionality to https://github.com/RRZE-HPC/likwid/wiki/likwid-perfctr#the-timeline-mode but at a higher frequency).  Is there a way to do this?  If so, what flags do I need to use when recording with `perf record` and reporting results with `perf report`?

So far, I've tried the following to retrieve the r6d70 performance counter at 5ms intervals during `sleep 5` execution: `sudo perf record -F200 -e r6d70 -a sleep 5`.  However, when I use `perf report` to view the outputted data, I see the following, which isn't really what I want:

```
Samples: 109  of event 'r6d70', Event count (approx.): 68432
Overhead  Command     Shared Object      Symbol
  33.77%  swapper     [kernel.kallsyms]  [k] update_blocked_averages
  10.30%  node        [kernel.kallsyms]  [k] update_blocked_averages
   9.07%  containerd  [kernel.kallsyms]  [k] update_load_avg
   8.98%  containerd  [kernel.kallsyms]  [k] __switch_to
   8.56%  node        node               [.] Builtins_LdaNamedPropertyHandler
   5.90%  swapper     [kernel.kallsyms]  [k] __sched_text_start
   5.88%  swapper     [kernel.kallsyms]  [k] cpufreq_this_cpu_can_update
   5.81%  nautilus    [kernel.kallsyms]  [k] update_blocked_averages
   4.56%  node        node               [.] v8::platform::tracing::TracingController
   3.82%  swapper     [kernel.kallsyms]  [k] arch_irq_work_raise
   3.20%  containerd  [kernel.kallsyms]  [k] select_task_rq_fair
   0.03%  swapper     [kernel.kallsyms]  [k] acpi_idle_do_entry
```

Comment: Can you explain better the issue you are facing? From your description I see you got 68432 samples over 5 seconds. Are you unhappy with the sampling rate, the data you got or the way it is presented?

Comment: I was hoping to get the counts of each specified counter over each sample period.  For example: [Sample 1] Counter 1: 234, Counter 2: 528 [Sample 2] Counter 1: 123, Counter 2: 321, etc.